# get my own metadata passed through literal in SOLR

Tags: android, jquery, solr, metadata

I'm trying to get my own metadata sent while indexing rich documents, using curl:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc21&commit=true&literal.urltofile=D:/Brain.pdf" -F "myfile=@Brain.pdf"
```

as you can see I added: `"literal.urltofile=D:/Brain.pdf"` to do the command.

I also edited the schema.xml, I added the field:

```
 <field name="urltofile" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

But when I use the query interface on Solr, I'm not getting that field on the result, the result I'm getting is:

```
{
        "id": "doc21",
        "last_modified": "2008-08-13T06:43:07Z",
        "author": "KHATRIMS",
        "author_s": "KHATRIMS",
        "title": [
          "Microsoft Word - New Microsoft Word Document.doc"
        ],
        "content_type": [
          "application/pdf"
        ],
        "content": [
          " \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n Microsoft Word - New Microsoft Word Document.doc \n \n    \n You could save a life.  \n \n  \n \n \nSTROKE: Remember The 1st Three Letters... \n \n S.T.R .  \nMy friend sent this to me and \nencouraged me to post it and spread \nthe word. I agree. If everyone can \nremember something this simple, we \ncould save some folks.  \n \nSTROKE IDENTIFICATION:  \nDuring a party, a friend stumbled and took a little \nfall - she assured everyone that she was fine and \njust tripped over a brick because of her new shoes.  \n  \n \n   \n (they offered to call ambulance)  \n \nThey got her cleaned up and got her a new plate of \nfood - while she appeared a bit shaken up, Ingrid \nwent about enjoying herself the rest of the evening. \nIngrid's husband called later telling everyone that \nhis wife had been taken to the hospital - (at 6:00pm \n, Ingrid passed away.)  \nShe had suffered a stroke at the party . \nHad they known how to identify the \nsigns of a stroke, perhaps Ingrid would \nbe with us today.  \n \n  \n \n \n Some don't die. They end up in a helpless, hopeless \ncondition instead. It only takes a minute to read \n \n this...  \n \n \n STROKE IDENTIFICATION: \n \nA neurologist says that if he can get to a stroke \nvictim within 3 hours he can totally reverse the \neffects of a stroke...totally. He said the trick was \ngetting a stroke recognized, diagnosed, and then \ngetting the patient medically cared for within 3 \nhours, which is tough.  \n  \n  \n \n   \n RECOGNIZING A STROKE  \n \nRemember the '3' steps, STR . Read and Learn!  \nSometimes symptoms of a stroke are \ndifficult to identify. Unfortunately, the \nlack of awareness spells disaster.  \nThe stroke victim may suffer severe brain damage \nwhen people nearby fail to recognize the symptoms \nof a stroke.  \nNow doctors say a bystander can recognize a stroke \nby asking three simple questions :  \n \nS * Ask the individual to SMILE ..  \nT * = TALK. Ask the person to SPEAK A \nSIMPLE SENTENCE (Coherently) (eg 'It is \nsunny out today'). \nR * Ask him or her to RAISE BOTH ARMS \n.  \n \nIf he or she has trouble with ANY ONE \nof these tasks, call the ambulance and \ndescribe the symptoms to the  \n  \n \n   \n dispatcher.  \n \nNOTE : Another 'sign' of a stroke is  \n1. Ask the person to 'stick' out their tongue.  \n2. If the tongue is 'crooked', if it goes to one side or \nthe other that is also an indication of a stroke.  \n \nA prominent cardiologist says if \neveryone who gets this e-mail sends it \nto 10 people; you can bet that at least \none life will be saved.  \n \n  \n \n  \n….and it could be your \n \n own…..  \n \n \nPASS THIS ON….  \n  \n  \n  \n \n  "
        ],
        "_version_": 1467891641052299300
      }
```

I need the field to be displayed on the result, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you fetching the results? Are you setting required fields on fl parameter?

Comment: I'm fetching the result using: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=brain&fl=*&wt=json&indent=true